# What should I pass to glfwSetWindowSizeCallback?

Tags: c++, opengl, window, glfw

From what I understand, the function in the title is necessary if one wishes to re size its OpenGL windows when using glfw.

From what I read in the documentation: https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#gaa40cd24840daa8c62f36cafc847c72b6, it has to be a GLFWwindow * and a GLFWwindow * parameters.

However if I try to declare a

```
 GLFWwindow * test;
```

I receive a error: ‘GLFWwindow’ was not declared in this scope|
This make sense since I am using glfw 2.7.9

The code I have it is:

```
if (!glfwOpenWindow (1024,768,8,8,8,0,8,0,GLFW_WINDOW)) {
  glfwTerminate();
  return 0;
}
glfwSetWindowTitle ("Test window:");
glfwSetWindowSizeCallback (/*what to put here?*/);
```

So, what shall I put there to make "glfwSetWindowSizeCallback" work?

Comment: What is your target language?  C++ or C

Comment: The language is c++.

Answer (score 2):

```
glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(m_Window, [](GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
            {
                 //Do Something
            });
```

I used lambda function for callback. You get pointer to the window , width and height of the window .You can do whatever you want in //Do Something area with the data you get from parameters.

Answer (score 1):

> I receive a error: ‘GLFWwindow’ was not declared in this scope| This
>   make sense since I am using glfw 2.7.9

Dont use 2.7.2. Its 7 years old.. Besides none of the functionality in your questions was introduced untill version 3.0. Instead get the latest version and read the following:

The function expects as its first and second parameter:

1. > The window whose callback to set.
2. > The new callback, or NULL to remove the currently set callback.

Example:

```
GLFWwindow* window;
glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(window, window_size_callback); // Set the to callback function name
void window_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    // What to do
}
```

Do notice that:

> The callback function receives the new size, **in screen coordinates**, of
>   the client area of the window when it is resized.

Therefor:

> Do not pass the window size to glViewport or other pixel-based OpenGL
>   calls. Use the framebuffer size, which is in pixels, for pixel-based
>   calls.

So if what your trying to achieve is to rezise the window using glViewport, instead do this:

```
GLFWwindow* window;
glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
void framebuffer_size_callback(window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

For more info, check [this tutorial](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html), specifically [this part](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_size).

Comment: but GLFWwindow does not exist in glfw 2.7.2. It gives me the "was not declared in this scope error.

Comment: Any reason why your using a version that is 7 years old?

Comment: Btw everything your trying to create above was introduced in 3.0 and so if you really want to use 2.7.2, none of the code above is valid.

Comment: Well, newer version demands cmake, and a newer version than the one is available for my distro. Guess I will have to download it and compile by myself.

Comment: Well, downloaded a newer cmake and it requires a C++11 complaint compiler, with my distro also does not have. So I would rather sticky with a 2.X version

Comment: Your to vagoue to be able to answer. Are you using a compiler from before c++? Get the latest compiler?

Comment: My compiler is g.c.c 4.4.3 with does not support c++11 and beyond. With that, I cannot build a newer Cmake and hence cannot build a 3.x glfw. I am thinking about building a newer gcc  by myself, but from what I have heard, It demands a lot of free space, space that I currently do not have available. Plus gcc is no ordinary program, to expose its newer libraries so applications can see it certainly requires lot of environment variables to be set and probably more stuff too.

Comment: Ummm. Good luck. With that.